# Hide notification dot if tabBar is hidden in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, uitabbarcontroller

I have in my application a notifications system. When a user get a notification, he can know it with a little dot on the tabBar.

[image]

My problem is that, when I want to hide the tabBar, the dot is still here:

[image]

I would like to hide the dot as well when the tabBar is hidden, but show it again if I come back to another controller (with the tabBar)

Do you have any idea about how I could do that?

Comment: `isHidden  = true`? Depends on the way you are adding the view. In general it should be part of the tabbar, so that it would hide automatically.

Comment: How is that dot overlaid in your view controller?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're trying to draw the dot manually over the tabBar.  I wouldn't recommend this, as your code will quickly get out of hand as you add/remove buttons and/or change orientations.

The easiest solution would be to utilize the built-in badge features for a UITabBarItem.  You can even customize the color to make it blue.  See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/1648567-badgecolor

Another option would be to create custom UITabBarItems, overriding the draw function to do the custom notification badges.

Either of these approaches would resolve the issue of hiding the badge when the UITabBar is hidden, as they allow the UITabBarItems to manage their own appearance.